# add more than one example for request body in post request in swagger

Tags: java, api, post, swagger, http-post

[Post request in swagger ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6teY3.png)

**Is there a method to add more than one example for request body using swagger annotaitons?**
I have added these annotations to create first example

```
@Data
public class RefCustomerGenderDto extends BaseDto<Integer> implements Serializable {
@ExampleProperty( value = "genderCode")
@ApiModelProperty( example = "1515")
private String genderCode;
@ApiModelProperty( example = "genderdesc")
private String genderDesc;
@ApiModelProperty( example = "1515")
private Long sortOrder;
```

}